# Why am I getting ModuleNotFoundError in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

[image]I have created a custom Django command, where I have imported models as shown below

```
# myapp/management/commands/send_birthday_emails.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone
from Employeetable.EVENTS.models import Event, EmailTemplate
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class send_birthday_emails(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Send birthday emails to employees'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        today = timezone.now()
        current_month = today.month

        # Get employees whose birthday is in the current month
        employees = Event.objects.filter(event_type='Birthday', event_date__month=current_month)

        for employee in employees:
            # Get the email template for birthday greetings
            email_template = EmailTemplate.objects.get(event=employee)

            # Compose and send the email
            subject = email_template.subject
            body = email_template.body
            recipient_email = employee.email

            send_mail(subject, body, 'your.email@example.com', [recipient_email])

            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'Successfully sent email to {recipient_email}'))
```

I have used the full path to models.py as you can see in the above imported module list

```
from Employeetable.EVENTS.models import Event, EmailTemplate
```

I have used the IDE to give the suggestion on the selection of path, yet I am getting below error

```
 from Employeetable.EVENTS.models import Event, EmailTemplate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Employeetable.EVENTS'
```

As per the rule I have placed my custom command file `send_birthday_emails` inside app/management/commands.

I have attached the screen shot for your reference to show the exact path of the file.

[image]

```
(venv) babu@babu-All-Series:~/PycharmProjects/Employeedata/Employeetable$ ll
total 168
drwxrwxr-x 5 babu babu   4096 Oct  2 15:58 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 babu babu   4096 Oct  2 11:57 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 babu babu 147456 Oct  2 15:58 db.sqlite3
drwxrwxr-x 3 babu babu   4096 Oct  2 15:45 Employeetable/
drwxrwxr-x 5 babu babu   4096 Oct  2 16:44 EVENTS/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 babu babu    669 Oct  1 15:10 manage.py*
drwxrwxr-x 3 babu babu   4096 Oct  2 12:17 templates/
```

This is the location from where I an running the below custom command

```
python manage.py send_birthday_emails
```

Please suggest where could be the mistake.

Thank You

Comment: You're missing an `__init__.py` in the EVENTS folder (that's why python is not recognising it as a module. Then `import from EVENTS.models`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your directory in my own system.

If I am using absolute import from project directory i am getting the same error

```
from EmployeeTable.EVENTS.models import Event, EmailTemplate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'EmployeeTable.EVENTS'
```

But if i am importing it from the app level like below :

```
from EVENTS.models import Event, EmailTemplate
```

it's working fine for me, give it a try once.

Comment: when I try "from EVENTS.models import Event, EmailTemplate", I am getting "Unresolved reference 'EVENTS' "  error.  I have added the screnshot.

Comment: for that please check your pycharm interpreter once and make sure you are using the interpreter with environment where you set up the project.